# Generating C# class from XML or XSD programatically

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, console-application

I have a backend application in production and need to update XSD and C# classes continuously after every update of XMLs that the application is receiving. I'm trying to write a C# code which I can run and it will automatically update both XSD and C# classes so I don't have to overwrite it by myself (there comes many new or updated fields each month and the validation is needed).

I managed to write a code that generates XSD from new XML but haven't seen any (open source) utility which would be able to create a C# class of objects based on one of these. I know I could use following:

```
Process.Start("....xsd.exe", params)
```

However, the solution should be generic for more users and the path of *xsd.exe* is not same for everyone.

Have you got any suggestions on how should I deal with that?

Comment: Why would you have to update the *schema* all the time? Schemas aren't generated from XML files, it's the other way around - XML documents are written so they conform to a schema. Changing the schema is a major, breaking change. Something's really wrong if a supposedly well-defined document structure changes all the time. If the schema changes so often, you probably shouldn't be using it to deserialize or to generate C# classes.

Comment: Even if the schema changes every month, you shouldn't have to guess it from the contents of a file that may or may not contain every element and combination. Why not use the actual published schema?

Comment: Your application architecture is all wrong here. If the schema is changing frequently, then data binding (mapping XML elements to C# classes) is the wrong design. And validating against a schema that is generated from the instance is useless - if you've generated it correctly, then the instance will always be valid.

Comment: The point is that we proivde new data samples to client with each change which we agree on. First of all we update the sample which we send them and they adapt their client side application according to the sample. Sometimes they have a problem sending a valid XML for some reason so we need to keep the xsds updated and its also more comfortable to work with objects inside our parser code instead of manually parsing the fields. Without updating the class programatically we would have to add an attribute manually every time something changes in desired data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I managed to write a generic *.bat* file which calls xsd.exe upon all needed xsds like so

```
for /R %%f in (*.xsd) do (
xsd /c "%%f" /outputdir:..\Objects /n:DataSource.Main.xsd.Objects)
```

and run this file programatically. The only con of this solution is that you need to add xsd.exe to your PATH.